# Is it possible to hide the methods inherited from the handle class in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm working on a command line application for ultrasound simulation in MATLAB. Nearly every object in our code is a subclass of handle (to pass as references). The problem I'm having is that all the methods inherited from the handle class shows up under the "Methods" section in MATLAB (see example below).

What I want is to hide the inherited methods from the handle class so that only the function the user is allowed to use is shown under "Methods". This way it doesn't look so messy for the user if he/she wants to know which methods to use.

Example Test class:

```
classdef Test < handle
    methods
        function myFunction(obj)
        end
    end
end
```

In the command line:

```
T = Test()

T = 

  Test handle with no properties.
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

After clicking on "Methods":

```
Methods for class Test:

Test         delete       findobj      ge           isvalid      lt           ne           
addlistener  eq           findprop     gt           le           myFunction   notify
```

What I want:

```
Methods for class Test:

Test         myFunction
```

Is this possible in MATLAB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a solution [here](http://www.tim.cz/en/nfaq/matlab-simulink/tab-completion.php), including sample code.

In short, what you need to do is to overload Matlab's built-in function `methods`, so that when it is called on your class, it removes the methods of `handle` from the output. Make sure it works on everything else, though so that you don't mess up your user's other code. If you don't use the `@foldername` variant to store your class, you could put it into a `private` directory, for example.

Comment: The link seems broken.  (I think standard policy is - or has shifted to - summarizing info from external links.)

Comment: @sage: Bummer that the link is broken. Fortunately, the second paragraph provides the summary.

Comment: Here is an old archive of the page from WaybackMachine: http://web.archive.org/web/20120103154712/http://www.tim.cz/en/nfaq/matlab-simulink/tab-completion.php

Answer (score 15):

If you overload all of the subclass methods in a hidden methods block I think it will do exactly what you're looking for.

I'm not sure which versions of Matlab this works in, but it definitely works for me in R2012b.

The exception is `isvalid` as it is Sealed so you can't override it in a handle subclass.

```
classdef handle_light < handle
   methods(Hidden)
      function lh = addlistener(varargin)
         lh = addlistener@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function notify(varargin)
         notify@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function delete(varargin)
         delete@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function Hmatch = findobj(varargin)
         Hmatch = findobj@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function p = findprop(varargin)
         p = findprop@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = eq(varargin)
         TF = eq@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = ne(varargin)
         TF = ne@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = lt(varargin)
         TF = lt@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = le(varargin)
         TF = le@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = gt(varargin)
         TF = gt@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = ge(varargin)
         TF = ge@handle(varargin{:});
      end
      function TF = isvalid(varargin)
         TF = isvalid@handle(varargin{:});
      end
   end
end
```

If you save the above class to handle_light.m and then type `methods handle_light` in the command window you will get the following result:

```
Methods for class handle_light:

handle_light  isvalid
```

The Test class then becomes:

```
classdef Test < handle_light   
   methods
      function myFunction(obj)
      end
   end
end
```

Doing it in this way means that you don't need to put the overloads in the Test class which keeps things neater.

Comment: Perfect!  I incorporated this (with trivial modifications) into my [matlab-utilities](https://github.com/ransage/matlab-utilities/blob/master/ThirdPartyTools/handle_light.m), which may be a better format for copy/paste since it has the attribution...

Comment: @sage that's great! I'm glad someone else finds it useful.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot thanks. One thing though `isvalid` made it on the handle method list - so you might want to update your answer.

Comment: @magu_ Then I get `Method 'isvalid' in class 'hidden_handle' conflicts with the Sealed method from
the superclass definition in 'handle'.`

Answer (score 2):

Not a full solution, but if you do `methods(T, '-full')`, then it at least tells you which methods are inherited from handle, so you know what to ignore.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a good thing to know about, but not quite what I was looking for. Maybe I should have explained it better in the OP. The main reason for me to do this is so users can use auto completion on classes without getting all the "useless" stuff from handle.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the functions from the inherited class and cancel them out with the ones from the main class using setdiff.

```
mH = methods('handle');
m = methods('MyClass');

m = setdiff(m,mH);
```